# TV show episode about alien music protecting humanity from radiation

Tags: story-identification

I remember seeing an episode from a sci-fi show where all human teens start hearing music and behaving erratically (more than usual). Then it turns out the sound comes from space and it induces a change in the human body that protects from, the soon going to increase, sun radiation.
I've seen this episode around 5-6 years ago in a channel with classic series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is ["Music of the Spheres"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_the_Spheres_(The_Outer_Limits)), from *The Outer Limits*.

> Devon Taylor, a young physics student, picks up a strange signal during his work at a radio observatory. He believes that he can hear a pattern in it, but **none of his older colleagues can hear it.**
>
> [...]
>
> It is determined that the source of this message is from a distant world and is in fact artificial in origin which implies it was sent from an intelligent source.
>
> [...]
>
> Devon is later reviewing photographs taken of stars at different periods in time and discovers that the star of the alien world went ultraviolet 40 years in the past. He brings this information to his superiors and the military. They then realise that **the radiation of Earth's sun is also changing to this spectrum**, heralded by increased solar activity. Further research indicates that the noise/music is being transmitted to cause life on earth to mutate and transform so it can adapt to the new conditions, and that **the alien transmission is in a sense a benevolent effort**.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe it was from the outer limits and I didn't remember.

Comment: I wonder if it was inspired by _The Music of Erich Zann_ by Lovecraft.